# Remove %20 from PHP header redirect using query string

Tags: php, redirect, header

I have a form I'm trying to submit to a database. Upon successful submission I would like the page to redirect to a page containing the submitted data. I'm doing this with a query string like:

```
header("location:palette.php?colID=$title");
```

Which is producing a URL like: **palette.php?colID=Funky%20Colours**

Is it possible for the PHP header redirect to redirect to a query like:

```
palette.php?colID=Funky-Colours
```

To produce a URL like: **palette.php?colID=Funky-Colours**

If so, can someone provide an example

Comment: Yes that is possible by replacing the character

Comment: Find and replace spaces with dashes, and do the opposite when passing  the value back to the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by simply doing:

```
header('Location: palette.php?colID='.urlencode(str_replace(' ','-',$title)));
```

But in your `palette.php`, `$_GET['colID']` will be receiving `Funky-Colours` instead of `Funky Colours`. So you need to use [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace) again to convert the dashes to spaces.

So, another question would be, what do you intend to do with those column IDs with dashes? For instance, the `$title` submitted is `Something-With-Dashes`, your script would turn these dashes into spaces. But to answer your question, **yes, it is possible to do this using [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace).**

Comment: That's perfect - Thank you.

The reason for me doing this is to grab the new data from the database that's just been submitted. 

Because I don't know how to use $id when it's not submitted by the user (it's generated by the database as a unique id) I'm using title to grab all the data **(WHERE title = $title)**